# DotSoft DoByLayer not Working

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

I downloaded DotSoft's DoByLayer tool for AutoCAD and ran the `NETLOAD` command as instructed on my AutoCAD 2016 product, but for some reason there is no `ORDERBYLAYER` command like there should be.

Does anyone maybe have any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Ideally you should not have to NETLOAD the plugin (DLL), the apps should load automatically according to its .bundle folder. But if you're NETLOADing it, make sure it's on a local folder (no network folders). Also, is there any error message? Where did you download it from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Augusto. I downloaded it from here http://www.dotsoft.com/freestuff.htm The download is a zip file that only contains the DLL's, an image and a htm file with the instructions on using the NETLOAD command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have do the following steps:

1. Unzip on a local folder (network folders are not supported by default)
2. Right click on the DLL, go to Properties and click on "Unblock" (if this option is not there, ok, no need to unblock it)
3. NETLOAD the proper version, I tried OrderByLayer19.dll (for AutoCAD 2016). Is there any error/success message?

Comment: You're a genius Augusto! It was indeed blocked, and when I unblocked it, it worked! Thank you so much for helping me! I am truly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

AutoCAD 2016 is not supported. The more recent version is for AutoCAD 2014 (OrderByLayer19.dll)

Comment: The thing is, it worked on a previous installation of Windows.

Comment: You are on Windows 10?

Comment: Well, I did install a clean copy of Windows 10 a month or so ago, and that may have been the Windows on which the plug in worked with AutoCAD 2016, but due to all the optimisation issues with Windows 10 I reverted back to Windows 8.1, which is the current installation the plug in does not seem to want to work with AutoCAD 2016.